# Cannot promote Server 2012 to secondary DC - yet everything else works?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

My specific error is: "An active directory controller for the domain corp.franzkromer.com cannot be contacted".

I am trying to add a secondary domain controller. My primary DC is also my primary DNS. The secondary DC is running DNS as well to backup the primary DNS (did a zone transfer and that seems to be working fine). I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 on both installations. The DNS address on my interface is set to be the primary domain controller with no backup DNS. An A entry was added for the new secondary DC.

Yet still, in Deployment Configuration for the would be secondary DC does not work. I am trying to "Add a domain controller to an existing domain". The user credentials are correct, and I have tried this with both the old win2k style domain name (in my case CORP), and with the modern convention (in my case, corp.franzkromer.com).

The secondary DC was able to be joined to the domain the usual way though. I even can log in as domain users on it. I have no issue pinging the FQDN or Netbios name of the primary DC from the secondary DC. I also have no issue pinging the secondary DC from the primary.

I have Windows Firewall disabled on both servers just because I was testing if that was the problem, maybe blocking some ports or something.

Something to note, the primary DC is a Hyper-V VM running on another, non-domain joined Server 2012 installation. The secondary DC is a VMWare VM running as a guest on a Fedora 24 Workstation (again, not domain joined). I have VMNet1 and VMNet8 interfaces both set to be part of the DMZ zone in Fedora.

I also tried without the secondary DC joined to the domain, just as a part of WORKGROUP and ran into the same error. Interestingly, if I wasn't domain joined, and I used the Netbios name I got an additional error "Verification of replica failed" as well as the same "An active directory controller for the domain CORP cannot be contacted".

Comment: For what it's worth, uninstall DNS from the new DC and allow the DCPROMO process to install it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My DNS on my primary DC was not configured correctly. I had to enable Active Directory integration on the zone then restart Netlogon to get the SRV records created. I discovered the problem by running dcdiag on my primary DC.